# C# client side to receive push notification (FCM)

Tags: c#, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a system in C# and I need to receive notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), because my client side is in C#. It is possible to receive these notifications?

I looked at the documentation regarding Firebase Cloud Messaging but I didn't find official support for client-side C#